# What kind of screws are used for the door knob of an interior door?

Tags: doorknob

When my painter took off the door knob of an interior door, he lost the two screws that held the door knob in place.  Does anyone happen to know what kind of screws they are?  They look like some type of Philips-head machine screws.

Comment: Off the top of my head I want to say 8/32 machine screws, but the length is important and can vary by manufacturer. If you have matching hardware on other doors, just pull one of the screws out and take it to the hardware store to find a match.

Comment: @Comintern That sounds like an answer to me.  Especially the part about taking a similar screw with you to find a replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately both screws were lost.

@Comintern: why is the length important?  It's OK if the replacement ones are a little shorter than the original one, right?

Comment: Isn't there another door with the same screws? Typically the screws that are with the knobs are long enough to accommodate thicker doors. As long as your door is only 1 3/8" it can be 1/2" shorter. Do not get them too long or the screw will bottom out before the handle is drawn tight. My guess is a 10/24 round head screw 1 1/4" long. The head may be too big to fit in the recess, since it will not be the original screws. They may be ground on a bit to get them to fit, in a pinch.

Comment: Find another doorknobin your house  from the same manufacturer, borrow one of the screws from there, make sure it fits the lost screw doorknob, then take it to your hardware store to match replacements.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I will take the door knob to Home Depot to find the right machine screws, now that I know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of the answers.  After bringing the door knob to Home Depot, I ended up buying #8-32 x 1" brass round-head machine screws, which worked perfectly.